Mediators in Causal Diagrams
I've been reading Judea Pearl's The Book of Why to try to understand how to use causal diagrams. On page 113, Pearl gives three events, A, B, and C, where A causes B which causes C. This is displayed as A → B → C. He says that B is a mediator, and we should condition on it.
However, on page 208, he talks about How taking a drug to reduce blood pressure reduces the risk of heart attack. He draws the causal diagram like this:
He says then that we should not condition on blood pressure, but it seems to me that blood pressure is the same as B in his earlier description, i.e. Drug → Blood Pressure → Heart Attack.
What is the difference here? Why shouldn't we condition on blood pressure?

Let $Y_x$ be the potential outcome of $Y$ if the drug level is set to $x \in \{0, 1\}$. Suppose you are interested in the marginal average causal effect of the drug on heart attack, i.e., $E[Y_1 - Y_0]$. In that case, you need to consider all the causal paths between the drug and the outcome, i.e., the mediated and the non-mediated. Therefore, you don't need to condition on the mediator because, by conditioning, you block the causal path that goes through the mediator. On the other hand, if you are interested in the conditional direct effect of the drug on the outcome, i.e.,
$
E[Y_{1,m} – Y_{0,m}].
$
Then you need to condition on $M=m$. Or, in the case of the natural direct effect
$
E[Y_{1,M_1} – Y_{0,M_1}], 
$
You will need to account for the distribution of $M_1$ in your calculations (clearly, not ignoring the mediator).
